# Problem loading Background Images from .json data

Tags: vue.js, quasar

I am consuming data from a .json file and using a **v-for** to iterate through all objects and create a card for each one of them, so far so good.

The weird thing is that for some reason:

1. Whenever I refresh the page the background-size COVER does not apply anymore and
2. some of the background images do not appear as it doesnt seem to be returning the background image URLs for some of the objects and I am absolutely clueless as to why

   ```
     <q-card-section
    style="
      background-position: center center;
      background-size: cover;
      height: 65%;
    "
    :style="`background: url(${experiencia.data.img})`"
    ><div class="row">
      <div class="col flex justify-end">
        <q-icon name="fa-solid fa-heart" class="text-h4 text-white" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="height: 100%">
      <div class="col flex items-end">
        <div
          class="text-h6 text-white q-mb-xl"
          style="text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px black"
        >
          {{ experiencia.data.destino }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   ```

[BEFORE REFRESH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQXNn.jpg)

Here you can see that COVER does not apply anymore as soon as I refresh the page:

[AFTER REFRESH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAWeN.png)

Here is the inspector, for some reason some of the images are not getting the background img url and others are not getting the background size COVER property:

[INSPECTOR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oxw7k.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `background` CSS property is a shorthand for a dozen background related CSS properties - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background
When you set it to the URL - you are resetting the other values to their defaults. You should use `background-image` if you want to set just the image URL.

Comment: That actually solved the problem! Yeah I was not taking that into account, thank you very much! At least the images are centered now and they stay that way. There is still the issue with some of the images not loading even though the route is the same. I mean all data objects in my .json file have the same structure, so $experiencia.data.img should be grabbing them all, and it is grabbing 90% of them, however... it remains an absolute mystery why those other couple of images are not appearing.

Comment: If there are no network requests for these images - probably the URLs are malformed and thus breaking the CSS rule.